# why it says "can not open file "python26.lib""?

Tags: dll

When I try to use the `cl -LD test.c -test.dll`, it says `can not open "python26.lib"`, why this happens?? thank you. (I was trying to generate a `dll` file by this command so that python could call it)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this [link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t677466-please-include-python26_d-lib-in-the-installer.html) - Hope this will help you -

This is caused by the following lines in the file c:\Python26\include
\pyconfig.h

```
# ifdef _DEBUG
# pragma comment(lib,"python26_d.lib")
# else
# pragma comment(lib,"python26.lib")
# endif /* _DEBUG */
```

So please:

1. Provide python26_d.lib in the
   installer.

or

2. Remove this automatic "pragma
   comment lib" from pyconfig.h, since
   I can't disable it from the outside
   (as far as I know).

Comment: thank you, I also searched this link, then I copy the python26.dll into my c file folder, it did not show the same error, but it showed : "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unsolved external"

Comment: @Serina - link user32.lib as well. Got from this link - http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7672. not sure if its related.